Row level security on select statement to select multiple rows from two tables
I have only used Postgres briefly, so still trying to learn.
I have 3 tables, "users", "teams" and then to connect users to multiple teams "users_teams".



users
users_teams
teams




id (PK)
id (PK)
id (PK)


name
user_id (FK)
name


...
team_id (FK)
...



I cant figure out how to set up row level security for the "users_teams" and "users" table to able to fetch the data. The teams table will be selectable for everyone so thats not a problem.
I cant figure out how to allow the user to fetch his data as well as getting the rows of other users connected to the same team as them.
Maybe this is not the right way to go about the table structure with RLS, so if you have a suggestions for a better way of doing it, then you are welcome to help me out.
I have only been focusing on getting the data from users_teams table for now.
I have tried a lot of different types of statements, but all of them return null from the database, which is strange, because when i only check on auth.uid() it returns the rights rows.
So it's almost like the OR statement is working.
here are some examples of what i have tried:
CREATE POLICY user_team_access_policy
on users_teams
to authenticated
using (
  user_id = auth.uid() or
  team_id = (
    select team_id
    from users_teams
    where user_id = auth.uid()
  )
)

or 

CREATE POLICY user_team_access_policy
on users_teams
to authenticated
using (
  user_id = auth.uid() or
  team_id in (
      SELECT team_id from public.users_teams where user_id = auth.uid()
  )
)

and many more.

The second one looks like it should work. What query did you run and what exactly did it return? A user should at least see the teams they belong to themselves. There might be a problem with reading from the users_teams table in the policy for the users_team table though - you may need to wrap that into a SECURITY DEFINER function that can peek behind the RLS restrictions.

@Bergi I was running a basic query:
const { data: test_data } = await supabase.from("users_team").select() and that returned null. but disabling the RLS worked.
But i ended up just creating a function for it. select team_id from public.user_team where user_id = auth.uid() and then calling it in the RLS using ((team_id IN ( SELECT private.get_teams_for_authenticated_user() AS get_teams_for_authenticated_user)));
How is it with having a function called so often when doing the auth checks for teams on every page. Is it the right approach as in regards to load on the server?

You'd have to benchmark to see whether there's much of a performance difference - though of course you'd first have to get a working version without a function to compare to. IIRC with SECURITY DEFINER the function cannot be inlined, but if declared as STABLE its results might be cached between rows (and in any case, the actual data for the current user will be in a hot cache, especially if there's an appropriate index on users_teams).
